# Calcular total de Id's idênticos

Tags: php, postgresql

Estou trabalhando com o `postgresql` , executando a seguinte query :

```
SELECT "tcfac"."co_cds_ficha_ativ_col",
       to_char(dt_ativ_col, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "data_atividade",
       to_char(hr_inicio, 'HH24:MI') AS "hora_inicio",
       to_char(hr_fim, 'HH24:MI') AS "hora_fim",
       "tcfac"."cod_equipe_ine",
       "tcfac"."qt_participante_ativ",
       "tcfac"."uni_codigo",
       "usr"."usr_nome",
       "uni"."uni_desc",
       "tctac"."no_cds_tipo_ativ_col"
FROM "tb_cds_ficha_ativ_col" AS "tcfac"
INNER JOIN "usuarios" AS "usr" ON tcfac.usr_codigo = usr.usr_codigo
INNER JOIN "unidade" AS "uni" ON tcfac.uni_codigo = uni.uni_codigo
INNER JOIN "tb_cds_tipo_ativ_col" AS "tctac" ON tcfac.tp_cds_ativ_col = tctac.co_cds_tipo_ativ_col
WHERE (tcfac.dt_ativ_col BETWEEN to_timestamp('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND to_timestamp('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
ORDER BY "tcfac"."uni_codigo" ASC
```

Que me retorna o seguinte resultado:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha dúvida é , seria possível somar a quantidades de uni_codigo iguais ? Pois vou utilizar isso em um relatório . Por exemplo duas dessas 4 pesquisas  são da mesma unidade .Acredito que trazer isso direto do banco é melhor do que tratar usando o PHP.

Fiz Algumas alterações na Query após alguns comentários porém o resultado saiu meio confuso . [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ela não contabilizou os Count's apenas informou um:

```
SELECT "tcfac"."co_cds_ficha_ativ_col",
       to_char(dt_ativ_col, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "data_atividade",
       to_char(hr_inicio, 'HH24:MI') AS "hora_inicio",
       to_char(hr_fim, 'HH24:MI') AS "hora_fim",
       "tcfac"."cod_equipe_ine",
       "tcfac"."qt_participante_ativ",
       "tcfac"."uni_codigo",
       "usr"."usr_nome",
       "uni"."uni_desc",
       "tctac"."no_cds_tipo_ativ_col"
FROM "tb_cds_ficha_ativ_col" AS "tcfac"
INNER JOIN "usuarios" AS "usr" ON tcfac.usr_codigo = usr.usr_codigo
INNER JOIN "unidade" AS "uni" ON tcfac.uni_codigo = uni.uni_codigo
INNER JOIN "tb_cds_tipo_ativ_col" AS "tctac" ON tcfac.tp_cds_ativ_col = tctac.co_cds_tipo_ativ_col
WHERE (tcfac.dt_ativ_col BETWEEN to_timestamp('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND to_timestamp('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
ORDER BY "tcfac"."uni_codigo" ASC
```

Comment: Pode utilizar o `GROUP BY`, mas por que essas 4 linhas seriam da mesma unidade sendo que duas possuem `uni_codigo` igual a 505 e as outras duas igual a 506?

Comment: Utilize a função de agregação COUNT juntamente com a cláusula GROUP BY. Se desejar apenas os que tenham duplicidade então utilize também a cláusula HAVING.

Comment: Anderson Carlos Woss, então realmente são pares não tinha me atentado a isso.O group by não funciona apenas quando uma row é idêntica a outra ?

Comment: Olá @LucasAlves, a resposta que elaborei soluciona sua pergunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer é retornar a quantidade total de `unidades` sem impactar na sua atual consulta continuando a retornar os **4 registros** (levando em consideração sua cláusula `WHERE`), certo?

Isso é possível sim e [simulei um ambiente semelhante ao seu](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9c508/2) com as querys de DDL e DQL (baseado nas informações contidas na sua `query`), somente para facilitar em minha explicação (*vale lembrar que ignorei a tabela `tb_cds_tipo_ativ_col` usado em sua consulta, uma vez que sua ausência não iria impactar na construção da resposta*).

Usei em minha solução a seguinte subquery que faz justamente o que você mencionou, realizando uma contagem de todas as unidades que estão contidas na query principal:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tb_cds_ficha_ativ_col" AS "2tcfac"
WHERE "2tcfac"."uni_codigo" = "tcfac"."uni_codigo") as "qtd"
```

Transformando sua consulta para a seguinte:

```
SELECT "tcfac"."co_cds_ficha_ativ_col",
       to_char(dt_ativ_col, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "data_atividade",
       to_char(hr_inicio, 'HH24:MI') AS "hora_inicio",
       to_char(hr_fim, 'HH24:MI') AS "hora_fim",
       "tcfac"."cod_equipe_ine",
       "tcfac"."qt_participante_ativ",
       "tcfac"."uni_codigo",
       "usr"."usr_nome",
       "uni"."uni_desc",
       "tctac"."no_cds_tipo_ativ_col",
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tb_cds_ficha_ativ_col" AS "2tcfac"
        WHERE "2tcfac"."uni_codigo" = "tcfac"."uni_codigo") as "qtd"
FROM "tb_cds_ficha_ativ_col" AS "tcfac"
INNER JOIN "usuarios" AS "usr" ON tcfac.usr_codigo = usr.usr_codigo
INNER JOIN "unidade" AS "uni" ON tcfac.uni_codigo = uni.uni_codigo
INNER JOIN "tb_cds_tipo_ativ_col" AS "tctac" ON tcfac.tp_cds_ativ_col = tctac.co_cds_tipo_ativ_col
WHERE (tcfac.dt_ativ_col BETWEEN to_timestamp('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND to_timestamp('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
ORDER BY "tcfac"."uni_codigo" ASC
```

Retorno da consulta feita no [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9c508/2), citado previamente: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só um comentário de uma frase sua: "*...Acredito que trazer isso direto do banco é melhor do que tratar usando
 o PHP....*" 

Isso depende muito do que é o seu conceito de **melhor** e de outros fatores como **complexididade da query**, **performance**, **manutenibilidade**, etc. Dentro da aplicação em que você está trabalhando. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado também por abordar a quentão da minha dúvida de qual erá melhor usar o banco ou a linguagem .Ajudou e muito.

Comment: Por nada, fico feliz em poder ajudar